# Gant script cacheing causing problems

Tags: grails, gant

this is driving me crazy - i'm trying to 'fix' a broken plugin and its using Gant scripts.

when i create a script it seems to run it - but if i create an error in a script and try and back the change out by deleting it - running the script a second time throws the same error.

i'm using the grails command history button in GGTS to run the script 'say test-script'  where i have a created  TestScript in the scripts directory.  Its like its somehow caching the scripts- and the last broken one seems to be the one it keeps running -

any ideas how to force it to reload the corrected script on the next run ?

Comment: Try running a `clean` command.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the class(es) from the `scriptCache` folder where they're compiled, which should be in your work directory (`target/scriptCache` or `target/work/scriptCache`),

Comment: ok - i've just buildConfig to store that in my local project target/work directory, rather than under .grails/...  however i am puzzled to understand why when i update the script and save (it should now be newer than the cache) - that grails doesnt spot that and recompile the script .  why do i have to clear the script cache manually?

Comment: I'm not sure, definitely seems like a bug because it does work sometimes. But it's a rare enough thing to do and easy enough to work around, so it hasn't risen far on my priority list.

Comment: just tried and its not that easy - i created a script and ran it  - i looked in the script cache and it creates xxxScript.class and a xxxScript$_run_closure.class.  When you try and delete through GGTS it errors - wheni try to do on the file system the xxxScript.class will go but GGTS has the xxxScript$_run_closure loaded in the VM - and it wont let you delete it.

Comment: is there a script i can call (ClearScriptCache say ) that would do an clean up and release the script and remove it?  at the moment i'd have to stop and start GGTS every time just to delete the cache!

Comment: do i log this as a jira issue - and more particuarly its a cow trying to fix this plugin i'm wrestling with - as every time i touch and edit a script in that plugin i fall into this issue - is there a cute tactical way to get round this ?

Comment: looks like cleanAll - is calling cleanWork target in _GrailsClean - which seams to release the lock in GGTS and cleans the script cache in the process - better than stopping /restarting GGTS - so do I need to raise a jira on the not refreshing the script cache issue ?  Also can a gant script trigger gradle - and i could try and rebuild the scripts i want as gradle actions, rather than gant scripts with the limitation outlined?